# How do I make my wxpython top frame show in the middle of my desktop?

Tags: python, user-interface, wxpython

I want to make my GUI program top frame both vertically and horizontally aligned.

```
wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent=None, id= -1, title="Test Frame", pos=(-1, -1), size=(1280, 770), style=wx.SYSTEM_MENU | wx.CAPTION | wx.CLOSE_BOX | wx.MINIMIZE_BOX)
```

What should I do(except do the calculation to find the absolute position) to `pos=(-1, -1)` to make it show in the middle(no matter 800 * 600 or 1280 * 800 etc.), or some other attributes setting also needed?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Simply use

```
self.Center()
```

in the class `__init__()` instead of `pos=(-1,-1)`.

Comment: Be sure to call `Center` after creating all child controls and `Fit` so the size is properly initialized.

Comment: At least on my system (Ubuntu 14.04, wxgtk 2.8.12.1), this does not account for an extended desktop configuration, i.e., the window may disappear from the main screen.

Answer (score 6):

```
w = wx.SystemSettings.GetMetric(wx.SYS_SCREEN_X)
h = wx.SystemSettings.GetMetric(wx.SYS_SCREEN_Y)

pos=(w/2, h/2)
```

This gives you the centre of the screen.

Now, assuming you have an 800x600 sized application:

```
APPWIDTH = 800
APPHEIGHT = 600

w = wx.SystemSettings.GetMetric(wx.SYS_SCREEN_X)
h = wx.SystemSettings.GetMetric(wx.SYS_SCREEN_Y)

# Centre of the screen
x = w / 2
y = h / 2

# Minus application offset
x -= (APPWIDTH / 2)
y -= (APPHEIGHT / 2)

pos=(x, y)
```

Comment: `pos=(w/2, h/2)` only makes the top left corner of the frame show in the center of the desktop, not the whole frame. Maybe there's no one-line attribute to do the job, calculation still needed I guess. Thanks anyway!

Comment: @Shane That's a given, the calculation I did will give the centre of the screen. Assuming you know the dimensions of your program, subtract half it's width and height, and the frame will be centred. I've adjusted my answer to show this.

Comment: there's a typo: `wx.SYS_SCREEN_y` should be `wx.SYS_SCREEN_Y` (note capital Y)